# Using Firebase Storage's putFile() method is resulting in: The file “fileName” couldn’t be opened error

Tags: ios, swift, url, firebase, firebase-storage

Here are two ways I've tried to upload the file:

1.

```
getURLOfPhoto(assetURL: imagesDictionary[String(whichProfileImage)]! , completionHandler: { (responseURL) in          
                                    FIRStorage.storage().reference().putFile(responseURL as! URL)
                            })
```

2.

```
  let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imagesDictionary[String(whichProfileImage)] as! URL], options: nil)
            let asset = assets.firstObject
            asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
                let imageFile = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL?

                FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("test").putFile(imageFile!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                        if let error = error {                   
                            return
                        }   
                }
            })
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
 Body file is unreachable: /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/picture.JPG        
    Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “picture.JPG” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."     
        UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/picture.JPG, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/picture.JPG,     
    NSUnderlyingError=0x15da49a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

The URL seems to be being retrieved successfully and the error only occurs when the `putFile()` method gets called.

Does anyone know how to fix this error or another way of uploading a file (not a Data object) to Firebase Storage?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the app crash or just log the error? If it says you don't have permission to view it I would check with the settings on Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The app doesn't crash, it just logs the error. My Firebase Storage rules are `allow read, write: if request.auth != null || request.auth == null;` so the read/write permissions on Firebase should allow me to write to the Storage Database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Firebase Storage is unable to use file URLs that are retrieved using the PHAsset based code I used in my question (or at least it was't able to in my experience) - even if those files are files the user took with the camera on their own iPhone.  So, one solution is to re-save the file in question to a location which is accessible to the Firebase Storage API and then upload the file by passing in that location's URL in to the putFile() method.

You can use this method if you're using the imagePickerController() method:

```
do {
   let documentsURL = FileManager.default().urlsForDirectory(.documentDirectory,
                                                                          inDomains: .userDomainMask)[0]
   let fileURL = try documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("fileName.jpg")

   let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]

   try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image as! UIImage,1.0)?.write(to: fileURL, options: [])

                    FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("exampleLocation")
                        .putFile(fileURL, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
    if let error = error {
                                print("Error uploading: \(error.description)")
                                return
                            }
                       }                
                 }
         catch {
            print("error is ", error)
        }
```

Comment: but you don't need try before the documents URL.. 

let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("fileName.jpg")

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that our uploader doesn't have the correct permissions to access that file due to the app sandbox (and we're pretty hesitant to grant broad file system access permissions).

I only recommend storing files in `Documents/` and `tmp/` per https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Granted, if it's coming from system resources, we might want to revisit that behavior. Typically I just do (yes, I know it's `data` instead of `file` and thus will have worse memory behavior):

```
  // pragma mark - UIImagePickerDelegate overrides
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    // Get local image
    guard let image: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

    // Get a reference to the location where we'll store our photos
    let photosRef = storage.reference().child("chat_photos")

    // Get a reference to store the file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
    let photoRef = photosRef.child("\(NSUUID().UUIDString).png")

    // Upload file to Firebase Storage
    let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/png"
    photoRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata).observeStatus(.Success) { (snapshot) in
      // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get it's download URL
      let text = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
    }

    // Clean up picker
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The URL was of a picture picked using the  imagePickerController(), would it not be reasonable for Firebase  to have access to that kind of URL? My app is multi-platform (Android & iOS) and I was unable to display an image in the iOS app that was stored in Firebase Storage using the putBytes() method of the Android API, so, it seems to make the Android and iOS apps able to retrieve the same images in the database I have to used files, so using putData() may not be an option for my app. Or can I make the images multi-platform available without storing them as files?

Comment: Allowing arbitrary file uploaders access to ones photos without user consent (or developer knowledge) seems to me like a huge potential security vulnerability. Imagine installing an app that vacuums all your personal photos and uploads them to a web server, all without you knowing.

Comment: As for the second: there's no difference between the in memory and file uploads from a compatibility perspective--at the end of the day, if you upload a JPG from an Android phone from memory, or from a file, it's stored the same way on the server. It sounds to me like there might be issues of converting between image types (like JPG and PNG), rather than storing/saving files.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Maybe the image stored in Firebase didn't display on the iPhone because it lacked the image's image type and/or the image was a WebP image. Anyways, images stored using putBytes() on Android can indeed be displayed on iOS devices. Also, if the file retrieved from the imagePicker is re-saved then it can be uploaded, so, unless the permission(s) the file uploader needs to upload files without re-saving them incurs an impact beyond allowing the app to upload files without re-saving them then perhaps not having that permission(s) doesn't have any real security benefits

Answer (score 1):

@Mike McDonald, thanks for your answer it worked for me. I was having the exact same issue and was able to solve with your suggestions. Here is my code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    guard let image: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage else { return }
    let profileImageName = "profileImageName.png"
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/\(Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() * 1000))"

    let photoStorageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(filePath)
    let photoRef = photoStorageRef.child("\(profileImageName)")

    let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/png"

    photoRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { metadata, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error uploading:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        } else {
            guard let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL() else { return }
            guard let downloadURLString = metadata!.downloadURL()?.absoluteString else { return }

            //do what I need to do with downloadURL
            //do what I need to do with downloadURLString
        }
    }
```

Hope this can help anyone else having the same issue!